# Assigning custom scrollbar CSS to div instead of body

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I am setting up a custom scrollbar that works across browsers, but my problem is that it is only being applied to the body (which is static), instead of the div scroll area, listed as 'content'. I believe the problem is in the javascript that lies at the end of the HTML, but I cannot unravel it.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <video autoplay="" muted="false" loop="">
            <source src="Media/BackgroundClip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="content">
            <header> <img src="Media/DOE_TMP.gif"> </header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div id="progressbar"></div>
                <div id="scrollPath"></div>
                <img src="Media/Dialogue4.png">
                <div class="text-wrapper">
                    >>>CONTENT
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let progress = document.getElementById('progressbar');
        let totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        window.onscroll = function(){
            let progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
            progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And the CSS used looks like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}
#scrollpath {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
#progressbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
    0%,100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#progressbar:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
#progressbar:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
```

Thanking you in advance,

Betty.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the position : 'fixed' for the progressbar. It should be absolute and the parent (.content) must be none static element (ex: relative). You can check it here: [custom scrollbar](https://jsfiddle.net/huycuong/8ftcoqbg/3/)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}
#scrollpath {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
#progressbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
    0%,100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#progressbar:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
#progressbar:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff, #00ffe6);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
.content {
  position: relative
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestions! Making the position absolute has brought the scrollbar into the div section from the side of the page, however, two problems remain: 1. The scrollbar is reading its progress + total height from the body section, which it is interpreting as 100%/100% (since the body is a single static page and only the content within the div is scrollable). -- I am wondering, should I wrap the scrollable section in a div class so that I can refer to it specifically in the <script> section>? 2. The default grey scrollbar is still appearing in Firefox. Any idea how to hide this?

Comment: Here's a picture of the problem for clarification:
https://imgur.com/a/Utw2EIQ